# 継承クラスの実行時、java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptionとなる

Tags: java

以下のBクラスのメインメソッドを実行したいです。

```
package package_35;

public class A {

    private void print() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    public void a() {
        print();
    }
}
```

```
package package_35;

public class B extends A {

    private void print() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    public void b() {
        print();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.a();
        b.b();
    }
}
```

コマンドプロンプトにて、以下の順でコンパイル、実行を試しましたが、例外出力されます。

```
javac A.java B.java
java B.class
```

```
エラー: メイン・クラスB.classを検出およびロードできませんでした
原因: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: B.class
```

回答への返信と結果：DEWA Kazuyuki - 出羽和之 様の回答にて意図通りの動作を確認しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 回答に対してコメントを付ける事ができるので、返信したい場合は質問に追記するのではなくコメント機能を使ってください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- (大抵の場合)class ファイルは package に従ってファイルシステム上に配置されている必要がある
- `java` コマンドは、 package 名も含めたクラス名を渡す

  - 質問文中で渡している `B.class` というのはファイル名なので誤り

という点を満たす必要があります。

具体的には、次のようにすれば良いです:

```
javac -d . A.java B.java
java package_35.B
```

次の回答にもう少し詳細に説明を記述していますのでこちらも参照してみてください:

- [Javaプログラムがターミナルから実行できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/54441/2808)

(注: この回答はJava11のころに行ったもので、[Java17の `javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html)は仕様が追加されているようですが、今回の質問の範囲においては影響ありません)